# Образования прилагательных

Tags: заимствования, словообразование, прилагательные

Прошу прощения за такую невнятную формулировку вопроса, постараюсь быть точнее, приведя пример: слово "сентенция", прилагательное, образованное от него, как я понимаю, будет выглядеть как "сентенционный"?  Либо "Казуистика" - "казуистический"? Есть ли общее правило для других подобных слов (оканчивающихся в конечном варианте на -ичный, -ический, -нный и т.д.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет простого правила для образования прилагательного единственно верным способом. Разные варианты словообразования могут складываться из практической потребности придать прилагательному тот или иной оттенок смысла. Для одних слов таких вариантов больше, для других - меньше. Например, образованные от сущ. "логика" прилагательные "логический" и "логичный" различаются по смыслу. Первое больше характеризует процесс, связанный с применением приёмов логики (логический вывод - вывод, полученный методом рассуждений о связи событий), а второе - результат (логичное предположение - разумное, внутренне непротиворечивое, к нему вполне можно было прийти логическим путём). Как правило, в конкретной ситуации эти слова не взаимозаменяемы. Варианты есть и для ваших примеров. Сентенция: сентенционный, сентенциальный и даже (узкоспециально в лингвистике) "сентенциативный". Казуистика: казуистический (явно их области казуистики) и казуистичный (суждение имеет оттенок казуистики, при всех его других качествах). Если для получения такого разнообразия не хватает суффиксов, они иногда переносятся из иностранного языка, например, "тенденциозный" (предвзято толкующий; tendencious), в отличие от "тенденционный" (связанный с тенценцией/-ями/, напр. "тенденционное многообразие"). С русскими словами так же: разные суффиксы придают разный смысл, например "удачный" (удар по мячу) и "удачливый" (везучий, часто забивающий мяч) - от "удача". Иногда и это путают, так что при выборе даже из знакомых вариантов ориентироваться нужно на смысл и сложившуюся практику употребления. Если этого не делать, употребление слова может оказаться если не явно ошибочным, то просторечным в конкретной ситуации, напр. часто путают слова "реальный" (существуюший на самом деле или способный к существованию) и "реалистичный" (о суждениях, предложениях и планах действия).